# Indexing columns for faster querying in MySQL 5.6 or higher

Tags: mysql, indexing, entity-attribute-value

I'm building a real estate app. I have a table called properties which is like the main table that has all common columns (10 columns) for all types of properties (lands, apartments, ... etc) and then I have a specific table for each property type since each type has some specific column. here is the property table:

```
CREATE TABLE `properties` (
  `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `property_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `property_description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_location_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` decimal(7,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` decimal(10,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` decimal(11,8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `entry_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_modification_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`)
)
```

and here is the apartments for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `apartments` (
  `apartment_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `num_of_bedrooms` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `num_of_bathrooms` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  `num_of_garages` INT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`apartment_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `properties_apartments_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`apartment_id`)
    REFERENCES `aqar_world`.`properties` (`property_id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

now the user can filter his search based on almost any of these columns or a combination of them, so how should I put my indexing strategy on the columns (the user could filter based on price, area, area and price, number of bedrooms and location and so on with these so many combinations) .. another point is that the property_description and property_title are texts so I'll have to add a fulltext index on each of them, right? also there is a join between these two tables and also between them and some other table (like agents tables for example).

I've read some say since mysql 5.6 there something in the optimizer that makes use of multiple indexes so you can put an index on each column but I don't know if that is right .. please advice since I'm not that good in taking care of DB performance

Comment: It's tricky when every column in potentially searchable, but I think you can start by examining your slowest queries and also the columns that make up joins in your queries, as candidates for a useful index. Furthermore, fulltext indexes are notoriously slow in MySQL and you may want to look into separate indexers, like Sphinx and Solr, which integrate with MySQL, to quickly process text search (and possibly geographical search, too).

Comment: Don't use `INT` for `num_of_bathrooms`.  Even Saudi royalty does not have 4 billion bathrooms.  Use `TINYINT UNSIGNED` - 1 byte (vs 4) and a range of 0..255.

Comment: 8 decimal places is precise enough lat/long to distinguish two roach motels sitting next to each other.  `DECIMAL(6,4)/(7,4)` gives you 16m/52ft resolution, which might be enough.

Comment: @Anton .. thx for the suggestion .. I'm considering apache solr for text search now ^_^ .. but as for the other columns, I have many columns in joins and different queries uses different columns, and since I'm testing, all queries seems to be very fast .. how to know the slowest ones? should I insert huge dump data for example and test or is there a better way?

Comment: @RickJames you are right, my table definitions uses a lot of unncessary space, I modified it .. thx a lot

Comment: @M.R.M I'd look at (1) settings and configuration (2) table structure and indexes and (3) queries, when it comes to performance. Often using `EXPLAIN` statements helps for (2) and (3), but I suggest doing some research and learning the basics first because there's a lot to it. I personally like loading my tables with large data because it allows me to accurately load test my applications (another thing to do later perhaps), and also if I do have small queries I get to experience the user frustration myself.

Answer (score 0):

5.7 has JSON tricks.  MariaDB 10 has Dynamic Columns with similar tricks.

The main principle:  Expose the more useful fields; throw the more obscure fields into JSON or Dynamic columns.  Then let MySQL filter on the former, and your app takes care of further filtering on the latter.

[More discussion](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Comment: i didn't quite understand .. could you please illustrate with an example or how to do that in mysql (using the workbench for instance)? thx ^_^

Comment: First, please read the documentation on those, plus search this forum on the 'entity-attribute-value' tag.